# iAd randomly crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, exc-bad-access, iad

I got this iAd crash randomly in my app. What could I do to fix? I don't see any hints for me to fix it because on the simulator it never happens.

```
Incident Identifier: CA4CBEB9-A081-459B-BAAA-C7D58A0E0ABC
CrashReporter Key:   e24b9614a897f92ee13ce00b76c71db307c61dcb
Hardware Model:      iPod2,1
Process:         FooApp [737]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F52C7226-7DA9-464B-939E-322394241900/FooApp.app/FooApp
Identifier:      FooApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-07-14 16:42:28.135 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0 (8A293)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000034f8 objc_msgSend + 24
1   iAd                             0x0000b88c -[ADBannerView _adManagerFailedToLoadBanner:withError:] + 68
2   iAd                             0x0000317c -[ADCache _notifyFailureCount:error:] + 160
3   iAd                             0x00003968 -[ADCache _dispatchResponses] + 332
4   Foundation                      0x000932a4 __NSFireTimer + 136
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00074256 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00076966 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1038
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000773ea __CFRunLoopRun + 1178
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
10  GraphicsServices                0x00003f88 GSEventRunModal + 188
11  UIKit                           0x00007b40 -[UIApplication _run] + 564
12  UIKit                           0x00005fb8 UIApplicationMain + 964
13  FooApp                      0x000023b4 main (main.m:11)
14  FooApp                      0x00002384 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00034e84 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00102a48 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00102494 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00102634 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b53c _pthread_wqthread + 392
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000ab0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002f94 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00074b18 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000770e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   WebCore                         0x0000370c RunWebThread(void*) + 552
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008af80 _pthread_start + 364
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d014 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000ab0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002f94 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00074b18 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000770e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   Foundation                      0x0003c316 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 210
7   Foundation                      0x0000c612 -[NSThread main] + 42
8   Foundation                      0x00092140 __NSThread__main__ + 908
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008af80 _pthread_start + 364
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d014 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00029f24 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0007aa54 __CFSocketManager + 340
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008af80 _pthread_start + 364
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d014 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008c3b4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b718 _pthread_wqthread + 868
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008c3b4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b718 _pthread_wqthread + 868
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x002caa60    r1: 0x3522f69a      r2: 0x002f3f30      r3: 0x05658530
    r4: 0x002e972f    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000003      r7: 0x2fffe9d0
    r8: 0x339e2ae4    r9: 0x2fffe91c     r10: 0x3522eede     r11: 0x3522da60
    ip: 0x3e668294    sp: 0x2fffe9a8      lr: 0x35217894      pc: 0x3523a4f8
  cpsr: 0x20000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x76fff +FooApp armv6  <5c2227d78f3ac0b30540b97024b286a9> /var/mobile/Applications/F52C7226-7DA9-464B-939E-322394241900/FooApp.app/FooApp
  0x674000 -   0x675fff  dns.so armv6  <d94bf29d2f94f4cac8fb25d075252bc2> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe28fff  dyld armv6  <a2a8d67606c76b315fd9e97b0b023784> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30021000 - 0x3007dfff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <4d09042d6dfd3c953a5c35fc9d765c7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3009e000 - 0x301c6fff  MusicLibrary armv6  <732057b3867dd3f90e600d1bcd217b2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x301c7000 - 0x30364fff  AudioToolbox armv6  <7ba1695e186fe8f284ab7f33fcd85d1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3041e000 - 0x3043cfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <806782dbc2e4e7992c26bf32b4df0674> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x304f4000 - 0x3055afff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <9222c722e8fa6b004565e9f50fb611c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x305a7000 - 0x305b6fff  OpenGLES armv6  <5f718500ced9ed538f6d70a20ca9e7b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x305b7000 - 0x305f9fff  CoreLocation armv6  <f851f4f9645c050445185f901c7d1426> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30659000 - 0x30692fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <d2cb48d8151eeecaac35f425543ed38f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x306f0000 - 0x30733fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <0a68cba6be455c7c40ab745a02f731c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x307b2000 - 0x30810fff  CoreAudio armv6  <667e016db146b7b685c2df973b4eb1f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30811000 - 0x30817fff  MBX2D armv6  <14a44e9271c3e17812a8ae9b690fbee7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x30836000 - 0x309b9fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <8fb72c9419ad2991e3883433a56474bd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x309bf000 - 0x309c7fff  IAP armv6  <393e2aa3ac1152c278788bdcdfcb0ae6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30aba000 - 0x30b1cfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <b08f7531c40c875a00655f20104bacf5> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x30b69000 - 0x30b69fff  vecLib armv6  <9675978ea23f63d6a50ba3e86b51ca97> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30c82000 - 0x30d66fff  QuartzCore armv6  <68467edfafbe46cf156a09f981470c4c> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30d6f000 - 0x30d8ffff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <096f09bbc077685818857b1b5b778180> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x30d96000 - 0x30de9fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <d97bf1093b1a64413eca6974fb0f5504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30e09000 - 0x30e0bfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <f5ef20a0bd9cba04ebc758fe6a23d3b7> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x30e0c000 - 0x30e0dfff  CoreSurface armv6  <0deb7e43538b2322b1393fef1c5a1590> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30e29000 - 0x30f43fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <32cb97fab65d624434be808e4d7f7fd5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3115c000 - 0x31160fff  ApplePushService armv6  <7f70dc415a34acff93861da7eabb7ba4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31162000 - 0x3152ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <9ed24071d90c47c237b42c77a5475efe> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x315a8000 - 0x315a9fff  liblangid.dylib armv6  <8f97ab552c7d6e16f592115d7477245a> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x315ae000 - 0x31666fff  ImageIO armv6  <00456ab6f056e5cc09947c1583de18bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3168c000 - 0x3168ffff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <45ad3a409dd6e9d3e7281b05a3819bc0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31759000 - 0x31765fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <acb852df8b8425700f2642c183362b71> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31766000 - 0x3176afff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6  <0049a3d14c57b4a1ea8d520fab571a92> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3176b000 - 0x3176dfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <f5356b424bc55d44d4151852098336c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x317d5000 - 0x3190efff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <eba90ac7da57bb6cf062d3a6e74b852e> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3193c000 - 0x31a10fff  WebKit armv6  <3cb517d6a799c4722ace6679f2e85a6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31a2b000 - 0x31a3bfff  DataDetectorsUI armv6  <c51cf579ae0d04d140e0714df48b6bae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x31a58000 - 0x31c99fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <16f68d9ce4e4e5bc18b35148d68c369a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x31e3a000 - 0x31e3efff  IOSurface armv6  <604ec9514f70a84f18a4c020b723ec57> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31e3f000 - 0x31f04fff  Celestial armv6  <d67abb27b59e69b05a98322b340e24d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31f3c000 - 0x31f47fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <ce0a82849bba4a1285bbccf145c02a35> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31f86000 - 0x31f91fff  ITSync armv6  <61f4bfaae86f26d0ff9a30d3fe6eff5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x31f93000 - 0x31f9dfff  MobileWiFi armv6  <597094bba2fbd7ee1976bd5f38d93f4c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31f9e000 - 0x31fdefff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <4c318efb9d60754af1f1ba5eee715880> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31ffe000 - 0x3200afff  DataDetectorsCore armv6  <0fb4f9f876e49398b15f1350155a0912> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x3200b000 - 0x3201cfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <ac2e94cd758efc73f8b4e9c298eac9d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3216a000 - 0x321b9fff  Security armv6  <b36cf795531d1d9e7be364e10d7ed90d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32233000 - 0x32285fff  IOKit armv6  <861fd5d810381967e6a4d8c504fddc65> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3235c000 - 0x33a75fff  UIKit armv6  <6b1e7386ccb9170130465dd66e320a58> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33a76000 - 0x33a8afff  libmis.dylib armv6  <d6b74e95f265c651ba519adbd525ab59> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33c07000 - 0x33c48fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <f599cd31636fd804c2cc820435577f5d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33c49000 - 0x33c57fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <336ba68fec36155d87dcd5cc93cb69a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x341e7000 - 0x34207fff  RawCamera armv6  <0d564a0ceaead3ed2c2ca062e6e86a9b> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x34209000 - 0x34239fff  AppSupport armv6  <fe42b18413be339f6f39abcc94c98a66> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x342b2000 - 0x342b9fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <e4d8805a067c32759705c7f750ae22d5> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x342ba000 - 0x342c0fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <b416e34658bd7794c3bfecefcec15827> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x342d7000 - 0x34342fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <c621f921d71ecad04aa90512945460f5> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34387000 - 0x34447fff  MediaPlayer armv6  <f56333ca810d4782f7952c0b56b329ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x34448000 - 0x34449fff  DataMigration armv6  <e172aff91163993f5487457a8a7fc481> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3445f000 - 0x34555fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <fe03fd73746bb5d1a66283f88af99085> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34556000 - 0x3455bfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <1fba30d031fdd1d3580a19d0e757f82a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3455e000 - 0x34566fff  WebUI armv6  <e02113f7b9eac918971ea0679e8d0e37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x3456e000 - 0x34573fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <82ebe32a298d9a3e2ff42c1fc4ed164b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x345a8000 - 0x345b1fff  AccountSettings armv6  <4933996569c9e94593eece3c59c83b38> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x345db000 - 0x345e3fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <480b2ebb3645728b3ddea392718b06f4> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x345f1000 - 0x345f5fff  libgermantok.dylib armv6  <118d3d5c40a44d2bc6540579b946f215> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x34638000 - 0x3463bfff  ArtworkCache armv6  <094874c28571b2a61958a12d7ac1c909> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x346c4000 - 0x347e5fff  Foundation armv6  <f332f35e00567975fd242ed36417e32e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x347e9000 - 0x3498efff  MediaToolbox armv6  <7abebed58aafad2637353798796827d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x349c6000 - 0x349d8fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <890d82cf86a38274a40c7435941825b0> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34a2d000 - 0x34a80fff  CoreMedia armv6  <791607fdea84db935ec2983b646fd6ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34c47000 - 0x34c89fff  AddressBook armv6  <8cdfdb51dfc5859a49e4e62f6f423458> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34d57000 - 0x34e5cfff  CoreData armv6  <17e10ccdd964bbceebc95ffcb9ad5d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34e5d000 - 0x34f6dfff  CFNetwork armv6  <1f59b619ceea0eaf7ba9ec3729c136d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x350c0000 - 0x35105fff  CoreText armv6  <ccd1c0b6e03bff58b013f9ef494f0ef8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3510b000 - 0x3512afff  Bom armv6  <9f17f2fdf0e7efd5740ff1d8637fc0b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35172000 - 0x35191fff  EAP8021X armv6  <d0c2bd846c2334cd5c9e801a9f466ca8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35192000 - 0x35195fff  MobileInstallation armv6  <d2dc5be30f11631cc7b90e48cff0f4e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35196000 - 0x3519afff  CertUI armv6  <dc80eb049f3baf955c238589529ab8ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x3519b000 - 0x351a7fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <564dcfd62a1a5430ec02feacf6334825> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x351a8000 - 0x351b6fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <712df47cb008c407ea7b3615d078cfc6> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3520c000 - 0x35233fff  iAd armv6  <9fd2305c151fe217c680bb5d92731eec> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x35237000 - 0x352ddfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <b55da671f23d1580dc031236c03ca977> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x352e0000 - 0x352edfff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <294e5422ae7533dd6c64fb5fef3b86e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x35348000 - 0x353e6fff  ProofReader armv6  <adaf06c1f87b025b35995394f3cf9c2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x355bb000 - 0x355bbfff  Accelerate armv6  <19360395982776b4e38e5a28acda450b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x355bc000 - 0x35719fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <e13b0847531b60aebfdb276c1eb5623a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x357e8000 - 0x358d1fff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <2c206f26fee7b7a93004b9f4e82b504b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35966000 - 0x3615dfff  WebCore armv6  <d2d1696c608f72e1451e7fe640ff840a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x362ab000 - 0x362e6fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <51e05cea58bdf27356c29658b5b93e6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x363a0000 - 0x36477fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <0ae5fe97433e816615033fbe19e5cf6e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x36478000 - 0x36484fff  CoreVideo armv6  <639962081f133b863b43981e3214c1e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x36485000 - 0x364c7fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <9f8575eaec0d1428fe23a40f2f7dd2c5> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36503000 - 0x36563fff  GMM armv6  <8f383b3fb65b1dd4e9e46d6de455ff29> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x365c4000 - 0x36600fff  QuickLook armv6  <d4e3461fd4185a86315ce004e0562382> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
```

Comment: I get the exact same error, and it crashes my app.
Have you found out a solution yet.
I THINK it happens when the device goes out of memory, because it always crashes after at least 20 minutes.

Comment: I have sent an email to Apple for an explanation but has not received the response yet. The answer below is not the right solution, don't know why it still gets upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you set delegate to nil on dealloc of main view.

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
banner.delegate = nil;
[banner release];   
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: awesome, after setting the delegate to nil, the crash is gone.
So far everything is good

Comment: so that mean i must cast ADBannerView as instance variable?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you handel all iAd properties correctly. I had the same problem but then I implemented the method didFailToReceiveAdWithError it fixed everything.

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError
*)error {   if (bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];        // assumes the banner view is at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50); // if the banner is on top of the screen use -50
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerIsVisible = NO;
    } }
```

Comment: I did implement these two delegates and it can show/hide ads. That error is not related to this delegate being called.

Comment: Ok then I don't know what to do. Maybe check for internet connection before calling the iAd?